# Does Oracle VirtualBox have any power management features?

Tags: virtualbox

I'd like to control VM guest's `virtual power` to provide me with a way to totally turn off a VM, or restart it.

Does VirtualBox support IPMI or any other power management schemes? I want to remotely manage the power.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp6694112

Scroll down to `VBoxManage controlvm`

Comment: Note well the difference between `acpipowerbutton` and `poweroff` - one sends the "shutdown" ACPI signal, the other yanks the (virtual) power plug.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about restart. but an `ACPI Shutdown` signal is available, which locates in `Control` menu.

Answer (score 0):

And I'll put my two cents in as well.
Today I was looked for the answer to the same question regarding IPMI functionality in Oracle VirtualBox and found this project in github:
[Provisioning Emulator with simulated BMC and Virtualbox](https://github.com/rmxymh/infra-ecosphere)

One more solution: [Virtualbox OpenStack Driver](https://cloudbase.it/virtualbox-openstack-driver/)